# Como agrupar e filtrar campos com JS

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando chegar no seguinte resultado utilizando lodash:

```
[
 {
   "idpai": 1,
   "pai": "joao",
   "mae": "maria",
   "filhos": [
     {"id": 1, "nome": "joaozinho"},
     {"id": 2, "nome": "pedrinho"}
   ]
 }
]
```

com o seguinte código:

```
var lista = [
  {idpai: 1, pai: 'joao', mae: 'maria', idfilho: 1, filho: 'marcos'},
  {idpai: 1, pai: 'joao', mae: 'maria', idfilho: 2, filho: 'joao'},
]

result = _.groupBy(lista, 'idpai')
```

resultado:

```
{
   "1": [
      {
         "idpai": 1,
         "pai": "joao",
         "mae": "maria",
         "idfilho": 1,
         "filho": "marcos"
      },
      {
         "idpai": 1,
         "pai": "joao",
         "mae": "maria",
         "idfilho": 2,
         "filho": "joao"
      }
   ]
}
```

Como estou utilizando lodash estou procurando algo que me possa ajudar, a minha lista vem duplicada assim porque é um banco relacional, existe alguma outra forma de resolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Amigo acredito que esta estrutura deveria vir do seu *backend*.

Acredito que não exista algo mais prático do que fazer com suas proprias mãos, fiz algo, um pouco de gambiarra, mas retorna a sua estrutura:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-hmyo8w

Answer (score 0):

Amigo utiliza o alasql
link: http://alasql.org/

Ele vai permitir você trabalhar como sql nos seus array javascript.

Espero ter ajudado amigo.